# Project not found when build docker container on Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, docker, azure-pipelines, cicd

I run commands to build and publish the docker image to registry but it fails with this error:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ./Project.Api/Project.Api.csproj
```

Project structure

```
src
 |--Project.Api
 |       |--Project.Api.csproj
 |-- Dockerfile
tests
azure-pipelines.yml
```

Docker task in pipeline

```
stages:
...
  - stage: build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    jobs:
      - job: build_container
        displayName: 'Build docker container image'
        steps:
          - bash: |
             docker login -u $(REGISTRY_USER) -p $REGISTRY_PASSWORD $(REGISTRY_URL)
             docker build -t $(REGISTRY_URL)/$(IMAGE_REPOSITORY):kkk . -f $(build.sourcesDirectory)/src/Dockerfile
             docker push $(REGISTRY_URL)/$(IMAGE_REPOSITORY):kkk
           
            displayName: 'Build and push docker image'
            env:
              REGISTRY_PASSWORD: $(REGISTRY_PASSWORD)
```

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY . /src

RUN dotnet restore ./Project.Api/Project.Api.csproj
RUN dotnet publish ./Project.Api/Project.Api.csproj --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.Api.dll"]
```

Does anyone know that is the cause of this error and how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow standard troubleshooting steps: Check what directory you're running that `bash` command out of. Put a `RUN ls` or similar command in your Dockerfile so you can check the directory structure within your container during build and confirm it's what you expect.

Your Docker context is likely set a directory level higher than you think it is.

You can set your working directory appropriately from there.

```
- bash: |
    docker ..
  workingDirectory: $(build.sourcesDirectory)/src
```

I'd guess that your code is ending up in the directory `/src/src/` in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Thank you so much. you saved my day. Setting workingDirectory to $(build.sourcesDirectory)/src solves my problem